# How to use both Column Transformer and Feature Union on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used ColumnTransformer to concatenate features that were scaled (numeric) and encoded (categorical) respectively in a pipeline; I want to use FeatureUnion to select features to be used by the model. Using cross_val_score(), I get nan values for my accuracy score. Help is appreciated, here's my code:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('scale', MinMaxScaler())])

cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('ordinal_enc', OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=np.nan))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, num_cols),('cat', cat_transformer, cat_cols)])

union = FeatureUnion([('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',bagging_freg=1,objective='multiclass')))])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('selected_features', union),('model', RandomForestClassifier())])

scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
print('Accuracy scores:\n', scores)
print(scores.mean())
```

The output cell displayed:

Accuracy scores:
[nan nan nan nan nan]

nan

Comment: I copy&paste your code and I got results using a toy dataset. Then, I think the problem is in the data you are passing as X_train and y_train.

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks. After this, how do I know the names of the selected features?

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem out, I didn't include the preprocessing step in my final pipeline. The correct version of the code is:

```
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('selected_features', union),('model', RandomForestClassifier())])
```